# Property losing value even though declared Public

Tags: c#, asp.net, properties, encapsulation

I've a file `SiteMinder.CS` in `App_code` where I set the `UserID` who has accessed the webpage

```
public class SiteMinder : IHttpModule
    {
        public string UserID { get; set; }

        public void Init(HttpApplication context)
        {
            context.PreRequestHandlerExecute += new EventHandler(Application_PreRequestHandler);
        }

        private void Application_PreRequestHandler(Object source, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (HttpContext.Current.Request.Headers != null)
            {
                NameValueCollection coll = HttpContext.Current.Request.Headers;
                UserID = coll["uid"]; // Doesn't have NULL value
            }
        }
    }
```

In another webpage `UserDetails.aspx.cs` file I'm trying to access this `UserID` but it is having `NULL` value.

```
public partial class UserDetails : System.Web.UI.Page
{

    protected string SessionUser { get; set; }
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SiteMinder objSite = new SiteMinder();
        SessionUser = objSite.UserID;//Returns NULL
    }
}
```

All these are under same namespace. Please let me know where I'm wrong here.

Comment: You need to call the init and Application_PreRequest to initialize the UserID. At this moment your are not calling them.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're creating a *new* `SiteMinder` object. That's not the same object that had the property set on it, so the property will have the default value (`null`).

You need to obtain a reference to the original `SiteMinder` object which set the property - or store the value somewhere else (such as the `HttpContext`).